# How can I fix a GTK 3 theme window border looking wrong?

Tags: gnome, themes, metacity, gtk3

This image speaks for itself:

[image: Picture of the issue]

The white line between the window border and the window body is not supposed to be there. I've seen other users dealing with the same issue but I've never seen a solution posted. The problem remains whether the theme is placed in `/usr/share/themes` or `~/.themes`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the theme a GTK 3 theme?

Comment: It is, it's called Elegant Revisited, it also comes with a Gnome Shell theme. I've been running it flawlessly on a previous Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white line appears because the text does not fit into the window border. Making the text smaller should fix it. You can do that by changing the widow title font size in gnome-tweak-tool.